# Just making sure I won't fry my motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, keyboard, damage

I'm building [this circuit](http://www.simprojects.nl/toggle_to_momentary.htm), which converts a toggle switch to a momentary one, which sends a key to a USB keyboard PCB by connecting 2 contacts together:

[image] [image]

I just wanted to check, how do I know the keyboard PCB won't get fried when I flip the switch to 12v DC? Or worse my motherboard?

Comment: Using a USB hub to protect your computer is always a good idea

Comment: @ScottSeidman only if the usb hub follows spec and is well engineered with protection features. Some hubs are a hub ic, 2 caps and an led, with VUSB directly wired from upstream to downstream ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentary buttons make a physical connection when pressed. The relay's actuating part, does the same. And unless you short a wire out or physically connect them wrong, you won't fry the computer or keyboard. The relay provides physical **isolation** between the coil and the actuating part.

Comment: Also known as "galvanic isolation".

Answer (score 1):

If nothing but the contacts goes to the PCB you won't hurt the computer.

If you want to be super-cautious, add a 0.1uF capacitor across the relay coil. That will ensure that when the switch opens, no serious spikes get coupled to the keyboard scan lines.

Comment: So how do I know I won't fry the PCB?

Comment: Because the contacts are not connected to the rest of the circuit (use your ohmmeter to test it!). OTOH, if you connect the 12V to the keyboard lines, for even an instant, very Bad Things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a resettable polyfuse would do the trick:

> ### USB Overcurrent Protection
>
> The [Arduino Mega2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) has a resettable polyfuse that protects your computer's USB ports from shorts and overcurrent. Although most computers provide their own internal protection, the fuse provides an extra layer of protection. If more than 500 mA is applied to the USB port, the fuse will automatically break the connection until the short or overload is removed.